# A simple regex expression

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

im having a little difficulty in making a regex that will filter an input for me.

if i get a lot of: `<option value=1234>text</option><option value=5678>text2</option>`
(note that the number is always 4 digits)
and i want the regex to filter the text for me, so i'll have a list of "text\ntext2" etc, 
what regex expression do i have to use? im kind of new to regex and i cant figure it out by myself..

thanks in advance!

Comment: *(obligatory)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: you want text\ntext2 or texttext2 as output??

Comment: i want each text in a new line:
text[newline]text2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<option value=\d+>([\w\s\\]+)</option>
```

Comment: that almost works (it wont find any 'text' that has a '/' in it.). it finds occurrences, but what do i write in the "replace with" field?

Comment: or <optiom value=\d{4}>([\w\s]+)</option>

Comment: how do i include the character '/' in it?

Comment: Just add \\. Backslash is an escape character, so needs putting twice. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to search replace within notepad++.

Search for

```
<option value=\d+>(.*?)</option>
```

and replace with

```
\1\n
```

Comment: Great regex, i haven't tried it because i already managed to do that i wanted, but it might make <option value=1>text</option><option value=2>text2</option>,    to:    text</option><option value=2>text2 - because it will search for the last </option> . i would try (i havent tried it and im new to regex) to go with: <option value=\d+>(.*?[^<])</option> so it will search 'text' until it hops into a '<'

Comment: Then instead of `<option value=\d+>(.*?[^<])</option>` use `<option value=\d+>([^<]*)</option>`.